# Eevee window shadow problem

Tags: mesh, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

Blender 3.0 Eevee: Basically when i render the scene that has a window with glass material mixed with transparent material and a light outside,the first seconds of the rendering the shadows are projected right, a cross in the wall, but then it messes all out as it continues to render and the shadows dissapear, what is wrong with it? file https://www.mediafire.com/file/ix2b2282z33ebz0/problem.blend/file

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take several seconds to display the shadows, at the beginning they will appear sharp. After that, the quality and sharpness of the shadows will depend on the settings of the *Render* panel, like for example the *Sampling* and the *Shadows* settings:

[image]

Also the light settings will count. For an *Area*, decrease the *Size* to get a sharp shadow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i changed the cube size do 4096px and the sampling to 350 to render and viewport and nothing changed

Comment: I forgot to tell, if you use an Area light and want sharp edges (not sure if this is what you want or want to avoid), decrease its Size value

Comment: Thanks it worked.